# R: How to uppercase first letter of each word split by semicolon in data frame column?

Tags: r, dataframe, lowercase

Suppose I have a dataframe `df`.

```
> df <- data.frame(Disease = c('Disease Entry1; disease Entry2', 'disease Entry4','disease Entry5; disease entry6'), ID = c(1,2,3))
> df
                         Disease ID
1 Disease Entry1; disease Entry2  1
2                 disease Entry4  2
3 disease Entry5; disease entry6  3
```

How can I manipulate it so that each Disease entry is all lowercase except for the first letter for each entry? i.e.

```
> df
                         Disease ID
1 Disease entry1; Disease entry2  1
2                 Disease entry4  2
3 Disease entry5; Disease entry6  3
```

I assume I would take use of the `tolower` function somehow, but how to take into account the semicolons?

Comment: Is it always the word `Disease` that's supposed to start with a capital letter? Or can the words change? If not, I'd recommend using `tolower()` and then use `gsub("disease", "Disease", df$Disease)`

Comment: Should have been more clear @KenS., `Disease` is just a placeholder I used for this example. It does in fact change.

Comment: You could use `stringr::str_to_title` to convert all words to start with upper case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can firstly convert all the letters to lower case, and then use `gsub` to convert the letters at BOS or after the `;` to upper case using back reference `\\1` together with `\\U`:

```
df$Disease <- gsub("(?<=^|; )([a-z])", "\\U\\1", tolower(df$Disease), perl = T)

df
#                         Disease ID
#1 Disease entry1; Disease entry2  1
#2                 Disease entry4  2
#3 Disease entry5; Disease entry6  3
```

Comment: Just for clarification, what does BOS stand for?

Comment: *Beginning Of String*. as the anchor `^` denotes.